# Error/logging message from "ON CONFLICT IGNORE" Sqlite3 clause

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to use a database table schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    student_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT IGNORE
    name TEXT
    grade INT 
)
```

I noticed that I'm getting the desired functionality from the ON CONFLICT IGNORE clause (i.e. no duplicate student_ids are inserted); however, I was wondering if there was a way to get SQLite to output a message anytime this occurs?  I'd like to make a warning/info logging message when this happens.

I've been looking through the official SQLite docs (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html), but there doesn't seem to be a native way to get such an alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was to using the default (i.e. "ON CONFLICT ABORT" clause) for the primary keys (to avoid the transactions from executing), and then use Exception catching in Python to feed my logging functions.